# How can I override transition delay?

Tags: css, menu, transition, dropdown

## Working Solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/tddfevhv/1/

I'm building a drop down type menu and some transitions are being delayed to give a nice animated effect to my list items.

However, this delay causes my background color change on hover to be slower than desirable.

A link to the jsFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/neuafy6j/1/

And here is the code:

```
.profile-list li {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -webkit-transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(-90deg);
        -o-transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(-90deg);
        transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(-90deg);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    }

    .profile-container:hover .profile-list .fourth {
        transition-delay: 0.6s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
        transition-delay: 0.6s;
    } 

    .profile-list li a{
        display: block;
    }


    .profile-list .first {
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
        transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
    }

    .profile-list .second {
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
        transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
    }

    .profile-list .third {
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
        transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
    }

    .profile-list .fourth {
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
        transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
    }

    .profile-container:hover .profile-list li {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
        -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
        transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
        transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
    }

    .profile-container:hover .profile-list .second {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }

    .profile-container:hover .profile-list .third {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
        transition-delay: 0.4s;
    }




        .profile-list li:hover{
        background-color: #e0e0e0;

    }
```

I tried setting a transition-delay: .2s !important; but that didn't help.

*Bonus question: Currently a tap on mobile opens the menu with proper animation. However the only way I found to close it is to click on of the links which reloads the page. If I turn of the default behavior with jquery to stop the page reload, it doesn't close the menu. How can I close the menu on a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT - with improved answer**

Here is the improved JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/neuafy6j/4/

The trick this time was to make the background-change not to the li but to the anchor tag. I took the padding from the previous li tag, added it to the anchor and it works like a charm:

```
.profile-list ul li a{
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    }
 .profile-list ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
  }
```

---

Previous answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/neuafy6j/2/ This JSFiddle might help you out.

```
  .profile-list li {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-top: 1px solid #e5e6e6;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        transition: background-color 0.5s ease!important;
    }
  .profile-list li:hover{
        background-color: #e0e0e0; 
    }
```

This is the important part. I added a transition with an !important tag that specifically focuses on the background-color only. The !important might be left out, but on an up-to-date Mozzilla I found it necessary.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Regarding the extra question: adding the :focus pseudo to all the :hover events is the most common way to achieve a hover-to-click change on smaller devices. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: that works but then it over rides the delay in the other transforms/transitions and you loose the delayed flip down effect. 

I think if I want to have the background color be separate I might have to use jquery or something no?

Comment: Oooh, I have just understood your problem now. Let me try to come up with something, I have a feeling it can be solved without jquery.

Comment: @AlexGray I editet my answer with a new, improved JSFiddle, check it out. I hope it helps

Comment: I actually had did that to the a tags my self to make the whole box a clickable link, so all I had to do the whole time was add 'a' before :hover. Thanks for helping me. Your answer wins :P Now I'm just trying to find my mobile solution.

Comment: Try adding :focus to all your hover effects, that is the easiest and also most common way to change hover to click on mobile devices.